# MARRIED : 47 :: BLESS :?

Tags: pattern

I am preparing for a competitive exam, and I am stuck on this problem which I found in one of the practice test.

I found this question on [tcyonline](https://www.tcyonline.com/tests/ntse-mental-ability-mock-test). The practice test is not accessible to everyone. The name of the competitive exam is [National Talent Search Exam](https://ncert.nic.in/national-talent-examination.php), which tcyonline offers practice mock exams for.

MARRIED : 47 :: BLESS : ?

Options are:

1. 62
2. 57
3. 26
4. 32

What is the answer?

Comment: Are we sure it’s 47? The word “married” is worth 41 in Pythagorean numerology. Depending on the font, a 1 can sometimes look like a 7.

Comment: Yes, it's 47. I am sure